# need to make the logo disappear in the small devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the d-none and d-md-block in the img tag to make the logo disappear in the small devices but it doesn't work so I tried to put it in the a tag but it makes the heading disappear too ,so how can I fix it

```
<header>
        <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-dark">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                    <a class="navbar-brand navbar" href="index.html"  class="d-none d-md-block">
                        <img src="images/19822_1_67_Thumb.png" alt="Logo image">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column p-2 pt-0 pb-0">
                            <h1 class="mb-1">David Chu's China Bristo</h1>
                            <p class="mb-1"><span><img src="images/star-k-logo.png" alt="Kosher certification"></span>Kosher Certified</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recreating this in a fiddle and it works as intended. Have you included the required css files?

Also, note that you have you two class tags on the navbar link, and you have the navbar set to an  tag.

https://jsfiddle.net/6gfqncyu/2/

```html
<header>
  <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <a class="navbar-brand navbar" href="index.html">
          <img width="50px" src="path/to/image.png" alt="Logo image" class="d-none d-md-block">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column p-2 pt-0 pb-0">
            <h1 class="mb-1">David Chu's China Bristo</h1>
            <p class="mb-1"><span><img src="images/star-k-logo.png" alt="Kosher certification"></span>Kosher Certified</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The navbar is a bit weird, I would recommend reading the docs, this could do what you want a bit more correct per the docs:

```html
<nav class="navbar bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="/docs/5.2/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="Logo" width="30" height="24" class="d-none d-md-inline-block align-text-top">
      Bootstrap
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```